# Cannot pass date into stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, date

Trying to pass date into a stored procedure as follows:

```
@dateRegistered = '28/04/2012'
```

But it keeps telling me:

> Error converting data type varchar to date.

It works if I do it as:

```
@dateRegistered = '04/28/2012'
```

But this is not the format I want to use.

I have run the following query to set the format:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
```

Why isn't it working?

Edit: Here is how I did it:

In my stored procedure, I put:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
```

Then from code, I pass it as:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@dateRegistered", SqlDbType.Date);
myCommand.Parameters["@dateRegistered"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

I passed it as string to ensure that even if my computer (or the server) has a different date format, it will always use dmy.

Edit Edit:

I passed it as datetime.now. It seems to transform it to the default format when I send it, and then transform it back to my computer format when I read it. Unsure how exactly this happens, but it seems to be working fine.

Comment: "I passed it as string to ensure that even if my computer (or the server) has a different date format, it will always use dmy.". **NO, NO, NO** Pass it as a DateTime - the .NET libraries know how to translate the .NET concept of datetime into the SQL concept, and don't need to muck about with any string formatting or ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the parameter is a `date` (in the database), while you try to pass a `string` (which corresponds to `varchar` in the database). If you instead pass a .NET `DateTime` object it should work as expected.

Comment: So how do you pass the date in the sql management studio? (For testing)

Comment: @TheGateKeeper in your case you could try `convert(datetime, '04/28/2012', 101)` (assuming you are using SQL Server). I am not a SQL Server master so there may be better ways.

Comment: If this answer were correct, it would also fail for the month-first format, but it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

Save yourself the headache and use an unambiguous date format - `20120428 (YYYYMMDD)` or `2012-04-28`.

As an aside: you mention you're using C# (based on the tags) - how are you using ADO.NET? Or is it Linq to SQL / EF / some other ORM?

Edit:

Ok, use the `CONVERT` function with an appropriate parameter indicating the format of your date string

EG:

```
declare @D datetime
set @D = CONVERT(datetime, '04/28/2012', 101)
print @D
```

`101` is US standard format `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Using convert will ensure it ALWAYS works regardless of any environment settings such as the date order.

Comment: It seems to work from code when I pass a datatime object... but I want to be able to test it from the SQL Management Studio too. Btw, I don't want to use the (YYYYMMDD) format.

Comment: `2012-04-28` doesn't work in SQL Server, for a `datetime`, if you've got `british` language set. (`20120428` does)

Comment: Can you please check If I did it correctly? I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `set dateformat dmy`, that only affects the current connection.  You'd have to set it every time right before you convert the string to a date.

The best solution is probably the ISO format, like @IanYates suggests.

Comment: So it isn't something you set for the database one time? I have to set it each time I pass a parameter?

Comment: Or better, pass a datetime `myCommand.Parameters["@dateRegistered"].Value = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: Can you please explain how to use the ISO format? If I call DateTime.Now wont this return the date with the format specified to the computer?

Comment: ISO format is `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`, note that `mm` means minutes, and `MM` months, [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

dear your code is working after using
*** SET DATEFORMAT dmy**
because you are passing date as "dd/MM/yyyy"
like "DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")"

check the date format in your database by following command :-

- dbcc useroptions

and check "dateformat : mdy" by default. So passing your date in "MM/dd/yyyy" format will also work fine.

Happy Coding :)